# Select Element Not Working in IE7

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I'm pulling a form into a site as an iframe. Everything works fine except there are two drop down select elements for the client in IE7 when they click it doesn't drop down but it highlights it and they can use their arrow keys to select.

I tried to test it with IE8 using compatibility mode and it worked just fine.

Any ideas on this?

**ANSWER:**
There was a z-index set on the site for some reason that was throwing it off. Once I set a higher z-index for those elements they worked.

Comment: When you open the iframe's contents in its own tab, does the `select` work, or is for sure only when in an iframe?

Comment: I was not able to reproduce as you described it; is there any CSS in play that specifies z-index?  You should post some of your code so we can narrow this down.

Comment: There was a z-index set on the site for some reason that was throwing it off. Once I set a higher z-index for those elements they worked. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @kel If you solved your problem, close the question please.

Comment: @firian How do I close the question?

Comment: @kel To close a question just click a "tick" image next to the answer you want to choose. In that case - click on the "tick" image which is located on the left side of your question (under the upvote/downvote images).

Comment: @firian I don't have that option for my own questions, take a look: http://img12.imageshack.us/img12/2882/c74e64a137464575ad3fdbe.png

Comment: I don't know why can't you choose your own answer as the best one - I've already seen people doing that. Maybe you should contact StackOverflow moderators?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a z-index set on the site for some reason that was throwing it off. Once I set a higher z-index for those elements they worked.

Answering my own question to mark it as closed. @Jacob gave me the idea to look at the z-index of the parent site.